# Countdown Timer Between Two Times (Not Dates)

Tags: vba, excel, timer

I have a small "Job Timer" that allows me to see how long I have spent on a job, and how long I have left to complete a job. It looks like this:

[image: Time Spent On Job Image]

The time spent on the job is correct, it works fine, however, the time remaining takes the start time of the job, adds the allocated job time to it and produces an "End Time". When I subtract the current time (`Now()`) from the "End Time", I get strange results.

Here is my code:

```
Public dismissed As Boolean
Public TimeUpdate As Integer

Public Function TimeSpent( _
Optional TimeStarted As Variant, _
Optional Allocated As Variant, _
Optional TU)

If Not IsMissing(TimeStarted) Then
TimeSpent = Now() - TimeValue(TimeStarted)
End If

End Function

Public Function Remaining( _
Optional TimeStarted As Variant, _
Optional Allocated As Variant)


If Not IsMissing(Allocated) And Not IsMissing(TimeStarted) Then

EndTime = TimeValue(Allocated) + TimeValue(TimeStarted)

Remaining = EndTime - Now()

End If

End Function

Public Sub TS()
x = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

TimeSpentForm.Spent.Caption = TimeSpent(Job.StartTime1.Value, Job.ACT.Value, TimeUpdate)
TimeSpentForm.Spent.Caption = Format(TimeSpentForm.Spent.Caption, "hh:mm:ss")


TimeSpentForm.Remaining.Caption = Remaining(Job.StartTime1.Value, Job.ACT.Value)
TimeSpentForm.Remaining.Caption = Format(TimeSpentForm.Remaining.Caption, "hh:mm:ss")

If dismissed = False Then
Application.OnTime x, "TS"
End If

End Sub
```

When routine `TS` is called for, the timer starts and the form is displayed, the routine will continue to run until the dismiss button is pressed (this works fine). But somewhere along the way the code goes wrong and instead of counting down from "1:00:00" (which is the allocated time in this particular case), it subtracts the "1:00:00" and goes to "23:00:00" and then counts up.

I've had serious issues with how VBA handles times and dates before in this manner, is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `=Time()` instead of `Now`

`Now` will return current date as well as time (DateTime) whereas `Time()` returns only the time portion.

(not relevant, but similarly `=Date()` returns only the date portion of `Now()`)

Edit: Also, as additional reference in understanding the implementation of date/time, do note BlackHawk's comments below.

Comment: Wow.. So simple, fixed the fault straight away. I can't accept this as the answer just yet because of the time restriction between posting a question and allowing it to be answered. But I will accept it as soon as I can!

Comment: As an addendum to this answer, Excel `Date` values are actually Doubles behind the scenes.  The [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Computing) of Excel datetimes is `January 0, 1900`.  The whole number part of the datetime value is the number of days since January 0, 1900 and the fractional part is the time - the fraction the day that has passed.  So for example, 1.5 would be 12 noon on January 1st, 1900.  You can see the underlying value of a date and time in Excel by typing it in normally (ex "7/7/2014 10:25 AM") and then formatting the cell as a number.

Comment: Excellent point, @Blackhawk. +1 for this. I'll add a reference to your comment in the answer.